# Вернуть элемент массива из файла

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть функция, которая загружает файл на сервере с разделителем \n в массив

```js
function load_file(success, error) {
    $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
        url: "bigfile.txt",
        success: function(data) {
            success(data.split('\n'));
        },
        error: function(e) {
            error(e);
        }
    });
```

Как правильно использовать такую функцию дальше в коде, для возврата элемента массива? К примеру, в другой функции перебрать в цикле все элементы

Comment: в `success(data.split('\n'));` и перебирайте массив

Comment: тогда так - как вернуть весь массив из функции, чтобы дальше работать в коде с ним?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290

Comment: @Igor если есть ответ, то это дубликат

Comment: @Alex Если я проголосую за закрытие дубликатом, то вопрос будет сразу закрыт. Хотел дать автору время свыкнуться с этой мыслью ).

Comment: @Igor золотая метка javascript ?)

Comment: @Alex Так точно.